# Irregular scaling of MATLAB figure axes

Tags: matlab, plot, zooming, figure

During my work, I got the figure shown below

[image]

It is clear that it turns out to be a mess below 5 on the y-axis. What I want to do, is to "expand" the y-axis **only** in the range from 3 to 5 such that the lines are separated and can be clearly distinguished.

I tried using `set(gca, 'Xtick', [0 1 2 3:.5:5 5:25])` but this didn't help at all.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: How about use log scale? If that doesn't fit your need, I guess you will need another figure (or *subplot*) with different *xlim* and *ylim*.

Comment: That would be bad practice, since it would leave you with a non-linear irregular axis. Why don't you plot a second figure (or a subplot) with a zoom in that area?

Comment: Using a log scale is not bad practice, that's the most commonly used form of analysis in Fourier transforms, error and power analysis for communication systems, RF, etc. to state a few.

Comment: @crazyGamer, I was answering to OP at the same time of the first comment. Log scale is fine! Stretching a region of the y axis not so much...

Comment: Oh haha, timing issues. Yes you are correct, partially stretching is not a good idea, an inset plot with zoom is better than that.

Comment: If you *really* want to do this you could scale those lines to take up more space then manually edit the yaxis ticks and tick labels. I think two plots showing `y<5` and `y>5` or the above mentioned zoom would be better

Comment: I have seen this situation a while ago, the person who had this problem put an insertion showing zoomed plot into the bigger plot. If you could show us an example code to get your graph, I can show you how. Or, if you don't bother messing with Matlab, just use PowerPoint or any picture editing software to add the insertion.

Answer (score 0):

What I got is as shown in the figure below:

[image]

Since I am getting my data through iterative loops and even sub-loops, I couldn't manage to get the desired figure using "inset plot", it got so complicated. However, what I did is simply that I had **two** MATLAB figures, the original one and another copy of it with a zoom-in of the y-axis from 3.5 to 5, then I copied the zoomed one to the original one and that's it.

This practice is better than using power point or paint to get the figure since doing so in MATLAB gives MUCH more flexibility in terms of editing the two figures, resizing them, axes labeling and so on.

Hope this would help someone else.

Comment: @SardarUsama I am not sure if I could do this for two reasons. First, it is not a single m-file with few lines of code that produced this figure, it's more that several m-files with hundreds of lines of code. Second, this work is supposed to be for a scientific paper that is **not** published yet.

Comment: Use some sample data for plotting alongwith how you adjusted that figure. Your exact work is not being asked here. Just a small working example. An experienced MATLAB user can understand what you did there but  it might not be clear for newbies.